# How to run production build of a ReactJS app with Parcel bundler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bundler, parceljs, parcel

I'm just trying to generate a build using parcel build /src/index.html,
I'm able to build the app, but when I try to open the build form a browser, it says it is unable to access index.js from index.html after build.

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="index.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

Anyway, Im having no issues on running the project locally.
Please take a look at the images below to understand my concern.
Thanks.

[image: Console error after opening index.html from build]

[image: Project structure]

Comment: Based on `file:///index.0b...js`, I would imagine your Parcel configuration is set in a way that expects all of the built files to be served from a server root.

In other words, your app could probably work if that directory was served by an HTTP server at `/`.

Comment: I tried pushing the dist folder onto GitHub Pages, but it didn't work that way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to serve the `dist` directory from a web server.

F.I. from your terminal:

```
cd dist
npx serve
```

Comment: It works that way, but I was looking for a solution that I can open it like a normal html page. Is there any way I can do so? I'm looking into it so that I can deploy it on GitHub Pages

Comment: Github pages are served from a web server, it should be fine as long as your js are served at /index.xxx.js

Comment: If your files are not served from / try something like --public-url ./ or --public-url /your-app-url/

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in scripts in package.json if it is an npm project

```
"build": "parcel build index.html",
```

This will give you an production build or simply run

```
npx parcel build index.html
```

And to run the application on local

```
cd dist
npx serve
```